# How can I make fql querys faster?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I'm trying to get a count of all the events that a user's friends have created using fql, but it is very slow, about 15 to 17 seconds to load.

Here is the code:

```
// Run FQL Multiquery to get all Friends => All Events => Created by Friends
$fql = $facebook->api('/fql?q={'
                     .'"allFriends":"SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()",' 
                     .'"allEvents":"SELECT+eid+FROM+event_member+WHERE+uid+IN+('
                                 . 'SELECT+uid2+FROM+#allFriends'
                                 . ')",'
                    .'"creators":"SELECT+creator+FROM+event+WHERE+eid+IN+(' 
                                       . 'SELECT+eid+FROM+#allEvents)"}'
                   . '&access_token='.$access_token);
```

Is there a better way to do this that will make it return faster?

Thank you in advance,
Robert

Comment: Sorry no, it doesn't work. It just returns a blank array. The query above works fine, but it costs me 4 seconds loading time.

Answer (score 0):

Chop the friends up into relatively equal portions (using LIMIT and OFFSET) and then run all those multi-queries in a batch call.